# Calculate the following improper integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

The exercise asks to study the convergence of integral $  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} \sin(x-y)e^{-x^2 - y^2} $.

It's easy to see, as a function $f: A \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, if and only if, the set of discontinuity points of $f$ has zero measure and the funcion $\vert f \vert $ is integrable in $A$, that $f(x, y):= \sin(x-y)e^{-x^2 - y^2} $ is integrable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because $\vert f  \vert \leq e^{-x^2 - y^2}$ and $e^{- x^2 - y^2}$ is integrable in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Now, **how to compute the integral** $  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} \sin(x-y)e^{-x^2 - y^2} $ ?

I've tried to use common changes of variables as polar coordinates or other linear ones, but it doesn't make things easier...

Comment: *Hint.* We have $f(-x,-y)=-f(x,y)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee so I guess $\int_{A} f(x, y) \: dx \: dy = 0$ as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} f(x, y) \: dx \: dy = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{[-a, a]^{2}} f(x, y) \: dx \: dy $  and $\int_{[-a, a]^{2}} f(x, y) \: dx \: dy = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute the antiderivative, it is not *"too difficult"* if you consider that
$$\int\sin(x-y)\,e^{-(x^2+ y^2)}\,dx\, dy=\Im\left(\int e^{i(x-y)}\,e^{-(x^2+ y^2)}\,dx\, dy \right)$$

Now, the exponent is
$$-(x^2-ix)-(y^2+iy)=-\left(x-\frac{i}{2}\right)^2-\left(y+\frac{i}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}$$ and you face gaussian integrals. So
$$\int e^{i(x-y)}\,e^{-(x^2+ y^2)}\,dx\, dy =\frac{\pi }{4 \sqrt{e}}\, \text{erf}\left(x-\frac{i}{2} \right)\, \text{erf}\left(y+\frac{i}{2}   \right)$$ Now, what is really unpleasant is to take the imaginary part of it.

It is doable, using for sure the $\text{erfi}(.)$ function